# Draw not debug lines in UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Really new for Unreal Engine 4.
My main point is draw transparent 3d object with sprecific border made by lines.
For these i have array of points which make lines.
so i have a procedural mesh for creating in c++ object, but it can only draw polygons.

After searching information about line drawing in UE4, have tried to use "draw
debug lines", but it is only for debug and only for 2 points (i need draw array of points)

so - my problem is : drawing lines in c++ code of UE4.

**how can i draw not debug lines?**

Comment: Check out the LineBatcher class: http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/ULineBatchComponent/index.html

Comment: There is no built-in solution to drawing line strips from an array of points as far as I know

Comment: thanks for LineBatcher. Try to use it

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array with all your linked point, why not iterate throught this array and create a DebugLine for each "linked points" ?

```
TArray<FVector> myArray = .... ;
for (size_t i = 0; i < myArray.Num() - 1; ++i)
{
    FVector LinkStart = myArray[i];
    FVector LinkEnd = myArray[i+1];
    DrawDebugLine(GetWorld(), LinkStart, LinkEnd, 
        FColor(255,0,0), false, -1, 0, 10 );
}
```

If you really do not want debug line, there is another method to [Drawline](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/FPrimitiveDrawInterface/index.html) in the SceneManagement from the `FPrimitiveDrawInterface` classes.(I've never used it, not sure it's the better solution for your issue)

In a harder way, you can use the procedural generation of mesh in C++, where you create mesh and populate vertices and edges. Take a look [at the doc](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Procedural_Mesh_Generation), and you may be able to adapt the code for your case

Answer (score 0):

For those who are struggling (like myself, once):

- **ULineBatchComponent::DrawLine** - if you are looking to draw in world-space (https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/ULineBatchComponent/DrawLine/)
- **AHUD::DrawLine** - if you need to draw on screen-space (https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AHUD/DrawLine/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30687665)

Comment: @justANewbie  Search with the **<name>**, which is the actual answer. The link is for convenience only.